# How do I save text input into preferences with onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: java, android

This app is simple and all I want it to do is just keep the text in the text field even after I close the app. I looked through some tutorials but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to save with `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. How can I do it?

Here is notes.java:

```
public class notes extends Activity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes);

        Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> How do I save text input into preferences with onSaveInstanceState?

You don't. `onSaveInstanceState()` is *only* for updating the supplied `Bundle`, with data that the user might like to keep if it works out (e.g., `onSaveInstanceState()` is called as part of flipping from portrait to landscape or back again).

> all I want it to do is just keep the text in the text field even after I close the app

Then `onSaveInstanceState()` is not the right place. Either save it in `onPause()`, or perhaps on an explicit action by the user (e.g., clicking a Save button or menu option).

Comment: How do i save it with onPause?